# Good text for writing a realtime physics solver?

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, software

What is a good, up-to-date, well-regarded text on writing physics solvers for (e.g.) game engines or realtime simulations?

In particular, treatment of numerical stability, convergence, asymptotic complexity and performance, contact forces, and the handling of constraints are relevant to me.

I have solid familiarity of university level physics, calculus, PDEs and ODEs, and linear algebra; and these can be assumed as prerequisites.

(An ideal book would be the analogue of [Pharr and Humphreys](https://www.pbr-book.org/), but for simulation)

What text(s) should I consult?

Comment: Related (possibly a dupe?): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595247/25301

Comment: Tangentially related, but not a dupe. I know what the prerequisites are and already have a solid understanding of them; I'm looking for rigorous information on algorithms and implementation details, which that question doesn't answer or provide references for.

Comment: This came to me for a 3rd strike for closing; two have already asserted that it is opinion-based. I like this topic so I'm going to skip. I'm also going to assume that you are not interested in simulating the electronic wavefunction in a material; i.e. assume that you mean only to solve for Newtonian trajectories. Turns out, new discoveries are still being made in both symplectic integrators and non-symplectic ones, even as computing architectures change. You might need to catch up on a lot of literature!

Comment: Agree; closing does not seem appropriate, as there is an explicit tag for resource recommendations, and these questions are hard to answer without insider knowledge. Thanks for sticking by it!

Comment: This wouldn't be the first time people have voted to close resource recommendations (it annoyed me enough years ago to [write this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9919/25301), though I was not at all a fan of the response).